# Importing "spinners" into google doc

Tags: excel, import

I'm looking for a way to import into google docs an excel sheet that includes spinners, which count when arrow is tapped. The sheet imports but the spinners disappear.

Comment: google docs spreadsheets do not support all of the features of excel sheets.  You may be able to do this using google apps scripts: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview